# add a directory inside freebsd jail

Tags: freebsd, zfs

Not sure if this is correct, but i have now installed freebsd 10 on top of ZFS with jails and have created a jail for Mongodb.

For the data files I used the following:

```
zfs create -o atime=off \
           -o compression=lz4 \
           -o exec=off \
           -o setuid=off \
           -o checksum=off \
           -o recordsize=8K \
           -o mountpoint=/data zroot/data
```

When I launch my jail as:

```
ezjail-admin console db
```

the `data` directory is not available

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of data files you need a jail for, and also not sure if you can use warden to create a data jail,

```
warden create data --ipv4=127.0.0.2/32 –startauto
```

then try `warden list` or `jls` and `jexec`